# How to configure Request Mapping of RestController manually

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-restcontroller, spring-rest

I want to provide the ability for a RestController class to have its mapping configured through a property.

So, instead of doing this in my rest controller:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/something")
public class MyRestController {

}
```

I want to inject the mapping into a `@Configuration` class with `@Value` annotation and then configure the controller class with that value.

So, it'd be something like this:

```
@Configuration
public class MyConfiguration {

  @Value("${something-mapping}")
  private String requestMapping;

  // ???
}
```

How do I do that?

Answer (score 0):

This is a restriction in Java annotations.All these values should be compile time constants.

Although you have tried this with `static final` variable, it won't help.

Tried with this implementation.

```
@Configuration
public class MyConfiguration {
    @Value("${something-mapping}")
    private static String requestMapping;
    public static final String REQUEST_MAPPING = getRequestMapping();

    public static String getRequestMapping() {
        return requestMapping;
    }

    public void setRequestMapping(String requestMapping) {
        this.requestMapping = requestMapping;
    }
}
```

It gives following error in the usage.

```
@RequestMapping(MyConfiguration.REQUEST_MAPPING)  // this line gives compilation error
    public String something() {
        return "something";
    }
```

Comment: Yes, obviously, you can't inject a value into the annotation. That's why the question was how to configure a RestController manually. NOT with annotations.

Answer (score -1):

You can make use of spring expression language (Sepl) . This way you can give the mapping string in `application.properties` files and configure your request mapping as follows:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/${something-mapping:something}")
public class MyRestController {

}
```

**Note:** The value after colon is the default value used when `something-mapping` is not found in `application.properties` file